# Binding multiple HTML attributes with AngularJS ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS, so forgive me if this is a noob question. The documentation is pretty terse, so I may have missed something obvious!

I'm considering migrating a bunch of custom in-house code to Angular, and I have to make Angular work with our REST pattern, in which an input looks like this:

```
foo: {
   value: 100,
   min: 50,
   max: 150
}
```

Value becomes the value displayed in an `input` element, and min and max are (currently) bound to min and max attributes. These are later picked up by a validation function. If value is outside of the min-max range, it is adjusted back into that range.

Anyway, I'm trying to do something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" my-bind />
```

... and override `ngModel` with a directive named `myBind` to manage the relationship, so that the value is read and written to `foo.value`.

I would then use a custom validator later to handle the min/max attributes.

Can anyone provide an example of how I might achieve such a binding? I've not had much luck making it work so far.

... or maybe my whole approach is stupid? I do have to work with the data structure above though, I can't change that in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand the question, but it seems like you could do this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="foo.value" max="foo.max" min="foo.min" />
```

If you still need a custom directive, you would do something like this to manipulate the ngModel:

```
angular.module('customControl', []).
  directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$apply(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

From the [AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) documentation.

Comment: I think the simplest solution might be the best, but I wonder if I'm coming at this all wrong. There is a REST service that delivers a bunch of data for input elements. Each one has the `{ value, min, max}` structure I mentioned up top. Where `value` is non-numeric, there usually is no `max` or `min` property specified.

Anyway, maybe I should be doing this differently, and splitting up max/min from the value elsewhere. My goal eventually is to use an integrated validator (i.e. part of Angular's validation system) to handle the max/min boundaries.